# Laravel Storage Link Won't Update after Image had Replaced

Tags: php, laravel

I have created storage link by this command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

The storage link its fine and I can access that file through Browser. The idea its I wanted to save user profile picture on that storage link `public/uploads/images/account/47.png`. My laravel act as Web Service (Serving RESTFUL API Only) to another system (let said react app + HTML on another domain)

Here is the response from the API if we required to access user profile picture

```
"acctType": "BS",
"regDt": "2020-05-15 10:36:26",
"photo": "https://abc.xyz/public/uploads/images/account/47.png",
```

The problem is every time we updating/replacing the 47.png, and we access through browser with entering this URL `https://abc.xyz/public/uploads/images/account/47.png` the image not changed.

Here is the code at laravel - PHP

```
if($request->hasFile('photo')){
$storage = Storage::putFileAs('public/images/account', $request->photo, $pq010->p9_pq010_acctid.'.png');
$storage_public = Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs('images/account', $request->photo, $pq010->p9_pq010_acctid.'.png');
```

I'm not sure what happened here. We have clear browser cache (by disabling cache on developer tools) and trying to `clear:cache`, `view:cache`;

Any idea about our issue? thank you.

Ps. We use laravel 5.8 at PHP 7.2

#### Update 1

I have checked the image over the FTP, yes the file had changed. But why my browser serves the old one?

#### Update 2

I also trying to delete file with this code and seems the problem on caching. The image was deleted but if We trying to access the image through link on the browser its still works.

```
$aaa = Storage::disk('public')->delete('images/account/'. $pq010->p9_pq010_acctid.'.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Laravel problem. It's browser caching. The easiest way is to rename file during upload. `47.png` to `random_hash.png` for example.

Comment: i have already mentioned that we running on developer mode with disable caching mode